# Multiple selection on a checkboxlist to filter a datatable vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, dataset, checkboxlist

hope you are doing fine.

I have a datatable loaded from a database. I bind the datatable to a gridview on page_load. Now I want to filter the gridview by a user selection so I made a checkboxlist and wrote some code as follow at CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Dim selectedartist As String = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim dTable As DataTable = Session("dTable")
    Dim dTablenew As New DataTable

    Dim str As String = "Song_Artist ='" & selectedartist & "'"
    dTablenew = dTable.Select(str).CopyToDataTable

    GridView1.DataSource = dTablenew
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

With this code above, it can filter if there is only one selection on the checkboxlist. I try to loop the checkboxlist myself but always ended up in errors. Hope someone can help me out to make this work.

Thanks so much.

L

This is the example of the datatable i have

[image: dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have already used a DataTable extension with `CopyToDataTable`:

```
Dim rows = From row In dTable.AsEnumerable()
           From item In CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem)()
           Where item.Selected = True AndAlso _
           row.Field(Of String)("Song_Artist") = item.Text
           Select row
If rows.Any() Then
    Dim tblFiltered = tbl.CopyToDataTable()
End If
```

[LINQ-To-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb386977.aspx)

Or in method syntax (in VB.NET not very readable)

```
Dim selected = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast(Of ListItem).
               Where(Function(i) i.Selected = True).
               Select(Function(i) i.Text)
If selected.Any() Then
    Dim rows = dTable.AsEnumerable().
        Where(Function(r) selected.Contains(r.Field(Of String)("Song_Artist")))
    If rows.Any() Then
        Dim tblFiltered = rows.CopyToDataTable()
    End If
End If
```

Finally, the NET 2.0 [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) approach:

```
Dim selected As New List(Of String)
For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
    If item.Selected Then
        selected.Add(String.Format("'{0}'", item.Text))
    End If
Next
If selected.Count <> 0 Then
    Dim rows = dTable.Select(String.Format(
                "Song_Artist IN ({0})",
                String.Join(",", selected)))
    If rows.Length <> 0 Then
        Dim tblFiltered = rows.CopyToDataTable()
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Tim ... this is brilliant work indeed. I try the datatable.select and it works as magic. Very much appreciated for the extras (LINQ) as well. I am trying to use more of LINQ but it is still hard for me. Have a nice day.